# Initialize const parent struct member from derived struct

Tags: c++, struct, constants

I'm writting a hierarchy of structs that all derive from the same base struct. Said base struct has a tag field that allows me to identify what's in it. Now I want to automate the initialization of that field so there are no errors, but don't want to write an initializer for each and every derived struct.

What I'm doing now is using an intermediate proxy struct to initialize the base one. A heavilly skimmed version of my header file would be:

```
enum class Tag
{
    Header ,
    Entry  ,

    Unknown = ~0
};

struct Chunk
{
    const Tag tag ;

    Chunk( Tag t = Tag::Unknown ) : tag( t ) {}
};

template< Tag TAG > struct ChunkProxy : public Chunk
{
    ChunkProxy( void ) : Chunk( TAG ) {}
};

struct HeaderChunk : public ChunkProxy< Tag::Header >
{
    int whatever = 0 ;
};

struct EntryChunk : public ChunkProxy< Tag::Entry >
{
    int somedata = 0 ;
};
```

I don't feel comfortable having that chunk proxy there, feels like there might be a better way of achieving this; and chunk can't be a template class itself, because I couldn't pass it around by pointer.

Note: I'm doing this to help me parse a chunked data stream, mapping memory read from the string directly to pod structs.

Edit: As per Archie's answer, I've added a constructor to Chunk and removed const_cast from ChunkProxy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a constructor to `Chunk`?

```
struct Chunk
{
    const Tag tag;

    Chunk() : tag(Tag::Unknown) {}
    Chunk(Tag tag) : tag(tag) {}
};

template<Tag TAG> struct ChunkProxy : public Chunk
{
    ChunkProxy(void) : Chunk(TAG) {}
};
```

Actually, with this constructor solution you may skip the `ChunkProxy` entirely:

```
struct Chunk
{
    const Tag tag;

    Chunk() : tag(Tag::Unknown) {}
    Chunk(Tag tag) : tag(tag) {}
};

struct HeaderChunk : public Chunk
{
    int whatever = 0;

    HeaderChunk(void) : Chunk(Tag::Header) {}
};

struct EntryChunk : public Chunk
{
    int whatever = 0;

    HeaderChunk(void) : Chunk(Tag::Entry) {}
};
```

Comment: The real thing is a bit more complex. I am specifically trying to avoid having to add a constructor to each and every substruct (there are lots of them).

Comment: @DiegoSánchez If you want to avoid this then the `ChunkProxy` (but with better name, maybe `ChunkTraits`?) is the way to go. Just don't do this `const_cast` thing as this introduces an UB.

Comment: Good point about the const_cast, added it in a hurry just to make the example compile. Will change it.